# i Want the following conversion for the table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

**CODE HERE` protected void BTRegPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText = "IDAUTOINCREMENT_PATIENT";
        int id = db.MAX_ID(cmd1);

```
    LabelActive.Text = 0.ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT_PATIENT";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", TxtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", TxtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAILID", TxtEmailId.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", TxtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONENO", TxtPhoneNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACTIVE", LabelActive.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", "Patient");
    db.NONRET(cmd);


    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd2.CommandText = "IDAUTOINCREMENT_MAPPING";
    int id1 = db.MAX_ID(cmd2);

    string chkbox = string.Empty;

    for(int i=0;i<CBLPhysicianlist.Items.Count;i++)
    {
        if(CBLPhysicianlist.Items[i].Selected==true)
        {
            chkbox = chkbox + CBLPhysicianlist.Items[i].Value.ToString() + ",";

        }

    }
    chkbox = chkbox.TrimEnd(',');


    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd4.CommandText = "INSERT_MAPPING";

    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id1);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PATID", id);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHYID", chkbox);
    db.NONRET(cmd4);

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Success')</script>");

    TxtEmailId.Text = "";
    TxtFirstName.Text = "";
    TxtLastName.Text = "";
    TxtPassword.Text = "";
    TxtPhoneNo.Text = "";
    CBLPhysicianlist.ClearSelection();

}
```

}`**

THE ABOVE CODE FOR BUTTON REGISTER CLICK.AT THIS I WANT TO PASS DATA TO THE TABLE PHYSICIAN_PATIENT_MAPPING..

Comment: This has to be one of the laziest posts I have seen so far. Please at least show *some* effort from your side. What have you done so far to solve your issue? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Comment: i have been trying to solve this from the morning...by that i found stackoverflow...am a new user..please try to help me ASAP.

Comment: SO isn't your code writing service. Show us what you have tried so far and explain what is going wrong. You should probably read the How to Ask page I linked in my first comment.

Comment: yea.. i'll say pass to this

Comment: i am sorry.i dont know how to explain it..because i am new to coding..please see the images..i guess you can understand it from those pics itself

Comment: At least see the images,and try..i really really need a solution for this...please help me

Comment: Homeworks everywhere!!

Comment: If it's only these 2 records, do it manually.

Comment: it is not....data will enter into the table when i click a button,which is for patient registration

Comment: See updated answer including sample code showing the concept that can be amended

Comment: FINALLY I GOT THE SOLUTION....HARD-WORK NEVER FAILS..THANK YOU ALL FOR GIVING SUPPORT AND SOLUTIONS.SPECIAN THANKS FOR @Nathangrad

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem would be to query your database table to get all records using the method of your choice.
Once queried, you can delete all records.
Run a loop on all records and use the `string.Split(',')` method on the `PHYSICIAN_ID` field to get a `string[]` containing all physician IDs for that record.
Once obtained, you can run an insert statement for each physician ID in each record to insert all the records as required.
Here's an example of what I mean in terms of C# code (documented by comments):

```
var table = new DataTable(); // Create table for storing query results

var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"); // Declare connection to server
connection.Open(); // Attempt to connect to specified server

var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", connection); // Declare query for server
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command); // Declare a data adapter for the query
adapter.Fill(table); // Execute the query

var deleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table", connection); // Declare delete statement
deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute delete statement

var strBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // StringBuilder for creating SQL statements
foreach (DataRow record in table.Rows) // For every row in the table
{
    string[] physicians = record["PHYSICIAN_ID"].ToString().Split(','); // Turn the CSV format into a string[]
    foreach (string physician in physicians) // For all physicians for that patient
    {
        strBuilder.Append("INSERT INTO Table (PATIENT_ID, PHYSICIAN_ID) VALUES ("
            + record["PATIENT_ID"].ToString() + ", " + physician + ");");
        // Append the StringBuilder with a statement to insert the new record
        // for every physician as applicable
    }
}

var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(strBuilder.ToString(), connection); // Create insert statements from the StringBuilder
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute insert statements

connection.Close(); // Close connection to the server
```

Comment: Am using Sql server 2008 R2...string.Split(',') is not applicable there,i guess

Comment: You need to use that method in C#, not SQL

Comment: for(int i=0;i<CBLPhysicianlist.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            if(CBLPhysicianlist.Items[i].Selected==true)
            {
                chkbox = chkbox + CBLPhysicianlist.Items[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
                
            }
          
        }
        chkbox = chkbox.TrimEnd(',');

Comment: this is how i pass my selected value to datatable,from the  checkbox list

Comment: help me out.really dont know how to explain

Comment: @Abhi Please post code inside the question, you can edit it, and then please use the Format Code option (select code, then click button **`{}`** in the editor)

Comment: @Nathangrad i do not know where to apply it...actually am using stored procedure..Am Really Confused...am new to Coding

Comment: Do you want this to be a one-time conversion from one format to the other or do you want it to be constantly updating? Edit your question to say exactly what you're doing for data entry

Comment: @Nathangrad Can you Please Give me your Mail Id,So that I can Send you All in image format

Comment: Please Help Me.....i must do this task before tomorrow.i i fail i will be thrown out from the office

Comment: FINALLY I GOT THE SOLUTION....HARD-WORK NEVER FAILS..THANK YOU ALL FOR GIVING SUPPORT AND SOLUTIONS